# If condition in case sql server

Tags: sql-server-2012

Following is my code. The inner query return null. I want to check if the value returned is null then I need to fetch data from some other query. How can I use if inside the case as my code is in case

```
WHEN a.col1=105 THEN 
          (SELECT Title FROM Test WHERE ID =(SELECT TestID FROM Test2 WHERE ID = a.colID)).
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `COALESECE()` the first query and call a second one in the event that it be `NULL`:

```
WHEN a.col1 = 105 THEN
    (
        SELECT Title
        FROM Test
        WHERE ID =
        COALESCE(
            (SELECT TestID FROM Test2 WHERE ID = a.colID),
            (SELECT ID FROM someOtherTable ...)
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function it returns the value if not null, if null, returns a second value:

```
WHEN a.col1=105 THEN 
  (SELECT Title FROM Test WHERE ID = ISNULL(
      (SELECT TestID FROM Test2 WHERE ID = a.colID), 
      (SELECT * FROM BLAH)
  )
)
```